# Проверить совпадение слова в строке с процентной вероятностью

Tags: python, python-3.x, поиск-библиотек

Задача найти/проверить слово в строке, ситуация когда слово/строка может быть искажена при парсинге пример: "1232_words&1231" или "word$",нужно найти "words". Достаточно найти 75% совпадения.
line_1 - слово которое ищешь. line_2 - где ищешь. 100 - это вероятное совпадения.

```
def find_word_per(line_1, line_2, percent=100):
    max_found = 0

    for item_1 in range(len(line_1)):

        for item_2 in range(len(line_2)):
            index_found = 0

            if line_1[item_1] == line_2[item_2]:

                for index in range(len(line_2) - item_2):
                    if item_1 + index >= len(line_1):
                        break
                    elif line_1[item_1 + index] == line_2[item_2 + index]:
                        index_found += 1
            if max_found < index_found:
                max_found = index_found

    result_per = (100 / len(line_1)) * max_found

    return result_per >= percent
```

Это мой вариант, он рабочий: [ссылка](https://github.com/AndreSci/Find-word-in-string-percent/blob/main/Percent_text_find.py)
Есть ли готовые решения в библиотеке python3?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конечно, такое есть - библиотека [TheFuzz](https://github.com/seatgeek/thefuzz), ранее она называлась [FuzzyWuzzy](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy).